# Insert data into database isnt working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a little stuck, I can update the database manually, but through PHP it isn't working.

database fields:

```
Column     Type          Collation          Attributes   Null  Default  Extra
id         int(10)                          UNSIGNED     No             auto_increment    
addedby    varchar(100)  latin1_swedish_ci               No            
location   text          latin1_swedish_ci               No            
details    text          latin1_swedish_ci               No            
deadline   text          latin1_swedish_ci               No            
datefixed  int(200)                                      No    0        
completed  int(11)                                       No    0
```

Add_jobs.php:

```
<?php

$pagetitle = "Add Job";

$checkrank = 3;

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.inc.php');


$helpfaerie = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM helpfaerie WHERE page = 'reportbug'"));
$helpfaerie2 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'"));

if ($helpfaerie2[helpfaerie] == 1)
{
echo "<div id=\"helpfaerie\" style=\"overflow: auto; position:fixed; bottom:0; right:0; \"><table width=\"200\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"4\" style=\"border-top: 1pt solid black;border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-left: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#ffffff;\">
  <tr>
    <td><center><img src=\"http://images.neopets.com/items/toy_faerie_psellia.gif\" border=\"0\"></center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>$helpfaerie[text]</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=\"text-align: right;\">[<a href=\"$baseurl/closehelp.pro.php\">x</a>]</td>
  </tr>
</table></div>";
}





ECHO <<<END






<center>
<FORM ACTION="add_jobs.pro.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" METHOD=POST>
<table width="366" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><center>Add Job<p></center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="118">Job Location (If any):</td>
    <td width="249"><textarea name="page"  cols="20" rows="1" value="" ></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="118">Details::</td>
    <td width="249"><textarea  name="wrong" cols="20" rows="10" value=""  ></textarea></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="118">Deadline::</td>
    <td width="249"><textarea name="line" cols="20" rows="1" value=""></textarea></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><center><font size="-1"><i>
      <input type=submit name=Submit value="Add Jobs">
    </i></font></center></td>
  </tr>
</table></FORM>
<p>&nbsp;</p></center>









END;




include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/footer.inc.php');


?>
```

Notes: dblink (is link to my database, which works fine,) Addon, is basically for smileys and grammer.

Basically this is to be a jobs page, which we update with jobs we need to do around the site.

add_jobs.pro.php:

```
<?php

$pagetitle = "Add Jobs";

$checkrank = 3;

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/addon.php');

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dblink.php');

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/security/stripusers.php');




$page = $_POST['page'];
$wrong = $_POST['wrong'];
$line = $_POST['line'];



$page = mysql_real_escape_string($page);
$page = stripslashes($page);
$page = stripusers($page);


$wrong = mysql_real_escape_string($wrong);
$wrong = stripslashes($wrong);
$wrong = stripusers($wrong);

$line = mysql_real_escape_string($line);
$line = stripslashes($line);
$line = stripusers($line);

if ((!$page) OR (!$wrong)  OR (!$line)) 

{

               die(header("Location: $baseurl/add_jobs.php?error=Please+do+not+leave+any+info+blank."));

}





else

{

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO assignments (addedby,location,details,deadline,datefixed) VALUES ('$username','$page','$wrong','$line','$timestamp','0')");

        header("Location: add_jobs.php?error=Thank+you.+Your+Job+has+been+submitted.");

}



?>
```

Ive just entered another issue.

Once Jobs are submitted, they then get listed on this

```
<?php



$pagetitle = "Active Jobs";

$checkrank = 0;


include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.inc.php');


$view=$_GET['view'];

$num = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `assignments` WHERE 1"));



if ($num <= 0)
{
    echo "


<p><center>

There are no active jobs :D";
}



$sort = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `assignments` WHERE 1");
while($sort2 = mysql_fetch_array($sort))


{





 if($sort2[id])


{

$tym = date("H:i",$sort2[date]);
$wcd = date("M j Y",$sort2[date]);  

echo("
<center>
<table width=\"607\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"4\" style=\"border-top: 1pt solid black;border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-left: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; \">
  <tr>
    <td width=\"139\" valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#5eaed4;\">Submitted By:</td>
    <td width=\"450\" valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\">$sort2[addedby]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#8cc7e3;\">Date Submitted:</td>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\"> $wcd @ $tym NST</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#5eaed4;\">Job Location:</td>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\">$sort2[location] [<a href=\"$sort2[location]\">View</a>]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#8cc7e3;\">Job Description:</td>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\">$sort2[details]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#8cc7e3;\">Deadline:</td>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\">$sort2[deadline]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#5eaed4;\">completed?:</td>
    <td valign=\"top\" style=\"background-color:#f4f4f4;\">Click When Completed [<a href=\"$baseurl/staff/submitted/completed_job.pro.php?id=$sort2[id]\">x</a>]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p></center>



"); }







}




echo "<p></center>\n";

echo "</center>\n";


include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/footer.inc.php');


?>
```

Which you then click a X and it then classes them as completed which then is meant to remove them off the page, but Its not doing do, they just stay listed,

But they are also registering that their fixed, and showing on the completed Jobs page.

completed_jobs.php

```
    <?php



    $pagetitle = "Active Jobs";

    $checkrank = 0;


    include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.inc.php');


    $view=$_GET['view'];

    $num = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM assignments WHERE completed =1"));


    if ($num <= 0)
    {
        echo "


    <p><center>

    There are no complete Jobs at this time.";
    }




    $sort = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assignments WHERE completed =1");
    while($sort2 = mysql_fetch_array($sort))


    {





     if($sort2[id])


    {

    $tym = date("H:i",$sort2[date]);
    $wcd = date("M j Y",$sort2[date]);  

    $ftym = date("H:i",$sort2[datefixed]);
    $fwcd = date("M j Y",$sort2[datefixed]);  

    echo("
    <center>
    <table width=\"607\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"4\" style=\"border-top: 1pt solid black;border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-left: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; \">
      <tr>
        <td width=\"139\" valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#5eaed4;\">Submitted By:</td>
        <td width=\"450\" valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\">$sort2[addedby]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#8cc7e3;\">Date Submitted:</td>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\"> $wcd @ $tym NST</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#5eaed4;\">Job Location:</td>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\">$sort2[location] [<a href=\"$sort2[location]\">View</a>]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#8cc7e3;\">Job Description:</td>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\">$sort2[details]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#8cc7e3;\">Deadline:</td>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-bottom: 1pt solid black;background-color:#f4f4f4;\">$sort2[deadline]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"border-right: 1pt solid black; background-color:#5eaed4;\">Completed On:</td>
        <td valign=\"top\" style=\"background-color:#f4f4f4;\">$fwcd @ $ftym NST</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p></center>



    "); }







    }




    echo "<p></center>\n";

    echo "</center>\n";


    include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/footer.inc.php');


    ?>

and then completed_job.pro.php


<?php


$pagetitle = "Completed Jobs";

$checkrank = 30;
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/addon.php');

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dblink.php');


$id=$_GET['id'];





mysql_query("UPDATE assignments SET completed = '1' WHERE id = '$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE assignments SET datefixed = '$timestamp' WHERE id = '$id'");



        header("Location: completed_jobs.php?error=Job+has+been+updated+to+complete+:)");



?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Don't call `stripslashes()` after calling `mysql_real_escape_string()`!** In fact, unless `magic_quotes_gpc()` is on (which it not recommended), don't call `stripslashes()` at all.  By calling it after `mysql_real_escape_string()`, you *undo* the escaping that function provides.

You have specified 5 columns in the insert column list, but supplied 6 in the `VALUES()` list. From your table structure my guess is you intended to include `completed` as well.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO assignments (addedby,location,details,deadline,datefixed) VALUES ('$username','$page','$wrong','$line','$timestamp','0')");
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

We assume the variables `$username` and `$timestamp` have been defined in one of the included files and properly escaped already.

Some error checking would reveal the source of the query error:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO assignments (addedby,location,details,deadline,datefixed) VALUES ('$username','$page','$wrong','$line','$timestamp','0')");
if (!$result) {
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: and for the coloums and Values thing, how did I not see that!

Comment: @Ellie Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If this or any other answer is satisfactory to you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

On first glance your insert query seems to have more values than columns:

```
INSERT INTO assignments 
  (addedby,location,details,deadline,datefixed) 
  VALUES 
  ('$username','$page','$wrong','$line','$timestamp','0')
```

This will certainly throw an error.

btw, the mysql_ family of functions are deprecated. You should at least use mysqli_ if not PDO.

Comment: Im not getting any errors, Just not having anything go into the database

Comment: mysql isn't deprecated. It's simply suggested that you use something else.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, it's not technically deprecated but recommended you use one of the other libraries: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 1):

You've got some syntax errors/gotchas:

```
$helpfaerie = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM helpfaerie WHERE page =  'reportbug'"));
```

You assume the query works. This is bad practice. Even if the SQL statement itself is syntactically perfect, it can fail for any number of OTHER reasons. You should ALWAYS check for query success before doing anything with the result of a query. e.g.

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

should be the bare minimum you have everywhere while developing/testing.

```
if ($helpfaerie2[helpfaerie] == 1)
                 ^--       ^--
```

You've neglected to quote the array key here. In this particular code snippet, the unquoted `helpfaerie` will be parsed as a `defined()` constant. However, it's probably not been defined, so PHP will "politely" auto-convert it into a string for you and throw a warning.

Then immediately afterwards you have

```
{
echo "<div id=\"helpfaerie\"
```

and output a massive blob of multi-line HTML. Yet later on you use a HEREDOC. Why not use one here too? It'd save you having to escape all of the `"` characters in your echo statement.

```
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($page);
$page = stripslashes($page);
$page = stripusers($page);
```

This makes not sense whatsoever. You escape $page properly, but then you do stripslashes, which essentially UNDOES the mysql_real_escape_string() call. While not totally accurate, you can consider m_r_e_s() to be an advanced version of `addslashes()`, so you're basically escaping, then unescaping again, leaving you vulnerable to SQL injection.

I don't know what `stripusers()` does, but regardless, the order of operations should be

```
$page = stripusers($page);
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($page);
```

m_r_e_s() should always be the **LAST** operation performed before you use that bit of data in a query string. If you do anything to an escaped string after the escaping has been done, you risk undoing the escaping and/or introducing another way for an injection attack to sneak in.